# Access 2010 How to differentiate between users with same name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database with student names. Each student has a unique ID.  I want to design a form to record which student visited library on which date.   My problem is that two or more students can have the same name.

Question 1: 
So how do I design a form to enter the date they visited library. I cannot expect person to remember student name and his id.  ID is nothing but an indexed column in Access.

Question 2:
How should I design a form? Should a user first search a student and then how do I add a record for that student?  Or Is there any field that will allow me to choose a student and populate his ID?

Any ideas?

Joe

Comment: Middle initial?

Comment: Name, first name and birthdate

Comment: I guess middle initial will make it less likely to find a perfect match with 3 names than with 2.

Comment: Hi, you can use an Unique User ID, generated from scratch, long enough to prevent *collisions*.

Comment: Are the students not given student numbers?  If so, use that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a relationship between `Students` and `Visits` table.

Then, on the `Visits` form, make a combo box from which you will choose student (the source of this combo will be query from `Students` table which will have additional details to identify, such as `middle name`, `birth year`, `city`, `hair color` or whatever you want)

and put a textboxes on this form for `Visit Date`, `Library` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that two or more students can have the same name.

Use LastName, FirstName MiddleInitial

So, set up the recordsource of your dropdown like this:

```
MyDropdown.RecordSource = "SELECT StudentID, " & LastName & ", " & FirstName & " " & MiddleInitial & " as StudentName FROM MyTable;"
```

Set your column count in your dropdown to 2, column sizes to 0;2 and linked column to 1.  Now, you will see the student names, but the .Value of the dropdown will be the StudentID, which you can use later.

> Question 1: So how do I design a form to enter the date they visited library. I cannot expect person to remember student name and his id. ID is nothing but an indexed column in Access.

You can either do this on a case-by-case basis or in a group.  In a case-by-case basis, just have a form with the dropdown described above, and a button that says, "Visited".  The button will send an Insert Into SQL string to input the date.  Like:

```
Dim MySQL as String

MySQL = "Insert Into MyTable ([StudentID], [LastVisited]) "
MySQL = MySQL & "Values (" & MyDropdown.Value & ", #" & Now() & "# )"

Currentdb.Execute MySQL
```

If you want to do it in a group, then use a Continuous Form to show all your students, put a checkbox on it to determine who was there, and then send them all at once in a loop.  It's going to require more work, and as a beginner it's probably going to lead to more confusion, so you might want to tinker with that form on the side.

> Question 2: How should I design a form? Should a user first search a student and then how do I add a record for that student? Or Is there any field that will allow me to choose a student and populate his ID?

Answered above